# Swift 4: Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type '[String : Any]?'

Tags: xcode, swift4.1

In a prepare(for segue:) I add the id:Int of the selected project into user defaults like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let viewController = segue.destination as? ReceiverVC, let project = sender as? Project {
            defaults.set(project.id!, forKey: "currProject")
            viewController.project = project
        }
    }
```

In my ApiRouter I need to access that value (I think I need it as a string since it is a URL parameter) but am getting

> "Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type
>   '[String : Any]?'"

with this code

```
let params: ([String: Any]?) = {
            switch self {
            case .getAllProjects:
                return nil
            case .getAllParts:
                return nil
            case .getProjectParts:
                return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "currProject")
            }
        }()
```

I don't know another way to capture the selected row and run back to the api to get the correct records

Comment: `params` is declared as a `[String: Any]`.  `UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "currProject")` that returns an `Int`. How is it suppose to match `Int` (value returned) `[String:Any]` (value declared)?

Comment: dunno ... that's why I asked the question

Answer (score 0):

```
case .getProjectParts:
  return ["your key":UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "currProject")]
}
```